Display null-values as nothing in pluto_grid number column type
I'm trying to create a grid where two columns are of type number and the fields are nullable.
final double? a; 
final double? b;

If a user adds a value to a, b will be set to null and vice versa but pluto_grid, version ^7.0.2, automatically display null values as 0.
I've tried to do add a custom renderer for these fields, but the value passed in to the custom renderer is 0 - even though it is null in the data source - so I have a feeling pluto_grid sets it to 0 internally.
I've tried to set initialValue: null among other things with no luck.
Here is a short code snippet that results in the second row having 0 in its number column where null is passed in.
return PlutoGrid(
  columns: [
    PlutoColumn(
      title: "text",
      field: "text",
      type: PlutoColumnType.text(),
    ),
    PlutoColumn(
      title: "number",
      field: "number",
      type: PlutoColumnType.number(),
    ),
  ],
  rows: [
    PlutoRow(
      cells: {
        'text': PlutoCell(value: 'Text 1'),
        'number': PlutoCell(value: 1),
      },
    ),
    PlutoRow(
      cells: {
        'text': PlutoCell(value: 'Text 2'),
        'number': PlutoCell(value: null),
      },
    ),
    PlutoRow(
      cells: {
        'text': PlutoCell(value: 'Text 3'),
        'number': PlutoCell(value: 3),
      },
    ),
  ],
);

I can probably specify the number columns as text, and create my own function that converts the types text into a number, but I would rather use the built-in support if it exists.
Any ideas?
